# Как использовать шрифты не с google fonts

Tags: html, css, css3

До этого всё время делал в head ссылку на шрифт в google fonts вот так `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">`

Теперь возникла необходимость использовать шрифт, которого там нет. В каком формате скачивать нужный шрифт и как его правильно подключить?
Пытался так:

```
h1{

    font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold', sans-serif;
    src: url('fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.eot');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Но как я понял для этого нужно использовать @font-face. Что это такое и с чем его едят?)

Comment: Здесь очень доходчиво объясняется варианты подключения шрифтов, и их нюансы ww.youtube.com/watch?v=GwA0BN5RgB0&t=7s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

файл шрифта подключается один раз в начале css следующим образом:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Semibold.svg#webfont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

в том случае когда у шрифтов разные файлы для отрисовки нормального начертания, жирного, италик и т.п. задаётся одинаковый font-family (например 'Proxima Nova') но в зависимости от начертания меняем font-weight и font-style

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova';
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
  url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Regular.svg#webfont') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

а затем можете использовать стили как обычно

```
h1{
   font-family: 'Proxima Nova', sans-serif;     
   font-weight: bold;
   font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: нужно указывать ссылки на все 3 расширения? Или достаточно одного? И что за формат svg?

Comment: лучше когда имеются хотя бы .eot и .woff
а svg  -  это формат векторной графики, некоторые генераторы шрифтов и его делают